# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.<init>

Tags: java, file, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am loading a file from disk , it contains 9,00,000 records.I am reading file line by line and processing it then setting to a java object.For each record the below code is executing(It will execute one insert,one update and one select query)

```
          try
          {

            if(conn != null)
            {

                 selectPrepareStatement.setString(1, someValue);
                 selectPrepareStatement.setMaxRows(1); 

                 rs = selectPrepareStatement.executeQuery();
                 String secondaryCIF = null;
                 insertPreparedStatement.setInt(1, vo.getRecordType());
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(2, vo.getRefType());
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(3, vo.getCustOwnershipType());
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(4, vo.getTin());
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(5, vo.getCifId());
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(6, vo.getPrimaryOrSecondary());

                Statement statement =  conn.createStatement();

                     if(vo.getPrimaryOrSecondary().equals("P"))
                     {
                         updatedCount = statement.executeUpdate("update table_name set col1='"+value1+"' where col2= '"+value2)+"'");                        

                         updatedCount = statement.executeUpdate();

                     }else if(vo.getPrimaryOrSecondary().equals("S"))
                     {
                            updatedCount = statement.executeUpdate("update table_name set col3='"+value3+"' where CUST_CIN = '"+value1+"'");
                            updatedCount = statement.executeUpdate();
                    }                


                 insertPreparedStatement.setInt(8, updatedCount);
                 insertPreparedStatement.setString(9, null);

                insertPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                }

             if(rs != null)
             {
                 rs.close();
             }              

        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

If I increase heap space to 1GB , then getting error after 3,00,000 records.Can some one please help me on this ?

All preparedstatements and variable are declared as global and static.

Comment: I'm quite surprised to see such bad-formulated question from such respectable and high-scored user as you

Comment: What is the size of this file (in MB)? Are you storing anything on each iteration ?

Comment: Ok, what is absent - is those lines of code where you are executing DB queries, it is essential

Comment: I was trying with so many solutions.So I posted in SO

Comment: Seems to me you are keeping al your read data in memory. But without more code it's hard for us define exactly where. Could be your prepared statement code or in TINDetailsVO or ...

Comment: `var4 = var4 != var4 ? var4.trim() : var4;` should be `var4 = var4 != null ? var4.trim() : var4;`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could you correct the indentation of you code, removing what is not necessary and show what is? This would be helpful (You should use try-with resource too)

Comment: The problem won't just be in your memory - Oracle itself will be creating a large rollback segment.  If you must do it this way you should be breaking it up into smaller chunks and committing each one.  A better solution would be to not use Java at all.  Use database tools to move data.

Comment: Consider using [Oracle's SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm) utility for importing the data.

Comment: @duffymo while using JDBC by default autocommit is true.Even then also am I need to take in chunks

Comment: Right, it's up to you to implement transactional behavior.

Comment: @duffymo Actually I have to get record from DB which matched to Id, then need to update .Can you pls tell me what exactly you are saying ?.Committing for each N no of records will solve my problem ?

Comment: A better solution would be to leave Java out of it altogether and to use database tools.  If you must persist with Java, you need to break the problem into smaller chunks.  Try 1000 records at a time.

Comment: Actually in our current project we have to do it in java only

Answer (score 2):

Generally you have to flush your DB session each N rows, because instead all data for DB execution will be stored in your memory until you will flush or commit it.

But because of very bad-formulated question (most essential part of codes omitted) I can not advice you more.

Comment: Thanks for reply.First of all sorry for bad formulated  question .My net has disconnected while posting this question and tomorrow once I reach Office I can formulate well.

Comment: Actually here I am using jdbc.Do you have any idea to flush in JDBC ?

Comment: In JDBC flush means commiting ?

Comment: This is JDBC 101: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html